# Uniquely Append to Array on Conflict PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, insert, tcpip

I've got two columns in PostgreSQL, hostname and ip. Hostname is the primary key and ip is an array of IPs.
I want to be able to insert IPs for a give hostname, on conflict I want to append to the array with the data I'm trying to insert and the output data should be unique.

## e.g

**hostname - ip**

test.com   {1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2}

### Input

I attempt to insert...

test.com {1.1.1.1, 3.3.3.3, 4.4.4.4}

### Output

test.com {1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2 ,3.3.3.3, 4.4.4.4}

```
insert into auto_scope_pre_proc (hostname,ip) values ('test.com', '{10.10.10.10, 10.10.10.22}'::inet[])
on conflict (hostname) do update
SET ip = array_append(auto_scope_pre_proc.ip,ip);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function array_append does not filter duplicates entries.
Here is a possible solution:

```
drop table auto_scope_pre_proc;
DROP TABLE
create table auto_scope_pre_proc
(
  hostname varchar(20) primary key,
  ip inet[]
);
CREATE TABLE
insert into auto_scope_pre_proc (hostname,ip) values ('test.com', '{1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2}'::inet[])
on conflict (hostname) do update
set ip = array( select distinct unnest(auto_scope_pre_proc.ip || excluded.ip));
INSERT 0 1
select * from auto_scope_pre_proc;
 hostname |        ip         
----------+-------------------
 test.com | {1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2}
(1 row)

insert into auto_scope_pre_proc (hostname,ip) values ('test.com', '{1.1.1.1, 3.3.3.3, 4.4.4.4}'::inet[])
on conflict (hostname) do update
set ip = array (select distinct unnest(auto_scope_pre_proc.ip || excluded.ip));
INSERT 0 1
select * from auto_scope_pre_proc;
 hostname |                ip                 
----------+-----------------------------------
 test.com | {4.4.4.4,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3,1.1.1.1}
(1 row)
```

Comment: I'm having a little trouble with this - for existing columns with a null constraint, even if they have data, the non-null constraint is being triggered.  As if I'm trying to make a new row without those values set :-/